# Scrollbar not showing in JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

Actually i am adding a Jlayeredpane to a Jscrollpane and then a Jlabel is again added to the Jlayeredpane. I am seeting the size of jlabel explicitly as jlayeredpane has null layout, In the Jlabel i am setting an image.

But the problem is that the scrollbar is not shown here.Please help in the design flaw or guide me to other alternatives.

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, shows your issue with PreferredSize for Layer(null layout)

Comment: ImageIcon icon = new  ImageIcon("output1.jpg");
imageview.setBounds(0, 0, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
imageview.setIcon(icon); // imageview is the Jlabel here
// and i am adding the jlayeredpane to jscrollpane

Comment: @Mohit: add the code to your question.

Comment: got it and solved by setting preferredsize. Thanks mkorbel

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Answer (score 0):

its may be you expected. but don't use null layout. JScrollPane not work with null layout.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ScrollLabel extends JFrame {

    public ScrollLabel() throws Exception {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        pane = new JScrollPane(panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        label = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("baby.jpg").toURI())));
        label.setIcon(icon);
        panel.add(label);
        add(pane);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ScrollLabel();
    }
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;
    JScrollPane pane;
}
```